# Downloading a web page with AutoIt is not working correctly

Tags: google-chrome, internet-explorer, firefox, browser, autoit

I'm trying an AutoIt script which uses the "Save As" download dialog from a web browser and gives a new name to the page downloaded. The page downloads correctly, but the problem is that it can't rename it, so the default name is used. I used the script whit IE, Chrome and Firefox but none of them worked.

Script:

```
WinWaitActive("Save As","","20")
If WinExists("Save As") Then
    ControlSetText("Save As","","Edit1",$CmdLine[1])
    ControlClick("Save As","","&Guardar")
EndIf
```

Example
[image: Example]
When I run it with "script.exe newname", the page should be downloaded as "newname", not "AutoIt simple example bla bla...." (default name)


**EDIT: Same code works with notepad save dialog, but It doesn't work on any browser.** 
**Also, I'm not using InetGet because that only downloads plain HTML. I need the complete page with css and images.** 
**EDIT2: I also tried this from java using AutoItX4java but that neither worked.**

Answer (score 1):

First, you are missing the `WinSearchChildren` option. Save/Open file dialogs are children dialogs.
Also no need to `&Guardar` string. that will make your script depend on the system language.

Here is the working code

```
#RequireAdmin ;Will give your script a permission elevation (sometimes its needed)
Opt("WinTitleMatchMode", 4) ;1=start, 2=subStr, 3=exact, 4=advanced, -1 to -4=Nocase
Opt("WinSearchChildren", 1) ;0=no, 1=search children also

WinWaitActive("Save As","","20")
If Not @error Then
    ControlSetText("Save As","","Edit1",$CmdLine[1])
    ControlClick("Save As","","[CLASS:Button; INSTANCE:1]")
EndIf
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried that script, it downloads the page but It still can't give a new name to it.

Comment: Then you are not passing the command line parameter right.
Try setting the static string in ControlSetText and see what happens.